# CPU is overheating and Ubuntu is not working

Tags: cpu, overheating

My CPU is overheating and Ubuntu is not working.

cpuidInfoAMD says : `NVRM cpuidInfoAMD: Unrecognized AMD processor`

My CPU is running very hot. It is an AMD Ryzen 5 5600x. My GPU is a Nvidia 3060 12GB.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04LTS. I also tried 22.10 with the same results.

All of the fans are working. When I entered Ubuntu, they started to spin very fast and I could hear the noise. When I was in Windows 11, everything was fine, but now it is laggy. The fans are spinning at maximum capacity

for reference the CPU temps in idle are like 72C

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Could you [edit] your question to include the version of Ubuntu you're running? Your processor is not so new that it should be reported as "unrecognised" unless you are using 18.04 or earlier.

Comment: Have you verified that all fans are working?  How long ago was the CPU heat sink installed (i.e. is the thermal grease reasonably fresh)?  And how hot is "very hot"?

Comment: Nmath, I gave more info, I dont think its a coling problem( I just bought it's a new pc and it was working perfect under windows11)

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you much: someone else might give you a better fix.

Try lowering your CPU clocks with cpufreq or similar... But I feel like that might fail. There's also a gnome extension that provides a graphical interface to regulate CPU clocks: if it is somewhat "intelligent" it may answer or solve the issue. Otherwise, you may want to try upgrading the kernel (I recommend using the mainline installer) or if that doesn't work use Xanmod kernel. Else I can only imagine you'd have to change some unknown (to me) configuration file...

In my case the os seems to recognize my CPU, but I noticed that kernels 5.x allow my CPU to run at 400MHz middle while 6.x refuse to run my CPUs lower than 1600MHz.

Comment: How do i upgrage the kernel?

Comment: Indeed a hardware issue, but the kernel has control over CPU clocks, thus it can throttle down if configured correctly. Lower clock speed means less energy per second consumed thus directly tackling the hardware issue of overheating. My advice is not "upgrade your kernel dimwit" my advice is: to investigate, kernels have control over power consumption. If I had the time to investigate all of that... But I don't and I'm not an expert in the os, I'm "just" a computer science student specializing in computation.

Comment: Regarding kernel the kernel upgrade, Xanmod is not "experimental" to my knowledge, and although it might have some issues, its benefits are a better adaptation of drivers.
https://www.linuxcapable.com/install-xanmod-kernel-on-ubuntu-linux/
I used this link for my installation: you can also use the mainline kernel installer to uninstall the kernel if it didn't work, and I would not remove old kernels from the system if I were you since you can always use them from boot.
https://ubunlog.com/ukuu-abandona-la-licencia-gpl-y-ubuntu-mainline-kernel-installer-ocupa-su-lugar/

Comment: And I would rather ignore this downvote since it seems it is usual for people to do this over here. The principle on which knowledge based systems work is by having a "logical explanation/derivation of facts" and a database of "anecdotes". Don't go downvoting people because you "think" that in "your opinion" I'm unknowledgeable. Bring out the facts and clear documentation and later donvote, else you're contradicting yourself.

Comment: Not all documentation is clearly specified and easy to find, I bet the kernel installs faster than you come to know what may be that you are searching.

Comment: You actually might want to check if the fans are working enough as @Nmath says up there: I for once have my fans controlled by hardware, thus the OS can't cause problems with that, yet to my knowledge, there's an option to  configure the fans with software in some setups.

Comment: Before you go and install a new kernel tho, I would check how do the CPU clock speeds compare from windows to ubuntu: if ubuntu has them at 3.2 GHz + which is what I suspect, then it is indeed an issue with CPU clock control. (My AMD Ryzen tends to operate at 4.78GHz on boot time, spiking temperature to 60 degrees, if left for a while it may reach 70 or 80...) I recommended upgrading the kernel since the kernel is directly responsible for control over drivers and such. You can check CPU frequency with watch /proc/cpuinfo or lscpu for additional information

Comment: If the checking of lscpu fails (or the other) then I'm pretty certain you have to either upgrade the kernel or find a hacky solution. You should also check, perhaps your CPU has a driver in the official amd website. https://www.amd.com/en/support

Comment: https://www.amd.com/en/support/cpu/amd-ryzen-processors/amd-ryzen-5-desktop-processors/amd-ryzen-5-5600x
It seems like it, but it works only for windows

Comment: Though the site does state that your CPU has ubuntu x86 64-bit support
Ensure you installed a pure 64-bit ubuntu Though I would find it strange if this were the issue (because the OS you installed might have 32 bit compatibility, but here I'm speculating), the rest is up to you unless you provide more detailed information -> and even then, learn to walk alone, it is good for you

Comment: kepler-22, About the temperatures, the same happens to me, I do like to note that now even when i enter BIOS(this is a new issue I just bought the pc and I didn't have those issues before installing ubuntu), I can hear the fans speed up and the CPU temps going up to 73Celsius.

Comment: While I was experimenting with Ubuntu, there was a time I broke my internet completely and couldn't turn it on even with windows (thus Ubuntu had corrupted something on the motherboard) if you suspect something's wrong with the bios, just factory reset it, it worked for me. Though you should consult your PC's manufacturer before touching anything on the bios. Have you tried using cpufreq?